# Apache CXF soap client using jCIFS SSL + NTLM authentication JDK 5

Tags: ssl, cxf, soap-client, ntlm, jcifs

I am trying to authenticate against a SOAP webservice using NTLM authentication as mentioned at  [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-NTLMAuthentication) with stack as following -

- jcifs-1.3.17.jar
- cxf-2.7.11
- NTLM + SSL
- JDK 5 (I possibly cannot change this)

Every time I try and connect it refuses with 401 unauthorized access because it uses my underlying NT credentials which are not authorised instead of valid ones that I configured in code. (I had to modify jCIFS as it doesnt support SSL + NTLM to return HTTPs version of NtlmHttpURLConnection). Similar result when used HTTP Async mechanism.

```
String domainController = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName(domainController, true);

jcifs.Config.setProperty("http.auth.ntlm.domain", "xxx.xxx.xxx");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "domain");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", dc.getHostAddress());
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "300000"); // 5 minutes
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.cachePolicy", "1200"); // 20 minutes
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", USER);
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", PWD);

//Register the jcifs URL handler to enable NTLM
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();

    HelloWorld src = new HelloWorld();

    ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean(new JaxWsClientFactoryBean());  

    factory.setServiceClass( IHelloWorld.class );  
    factory.setAddress(SERVICE_URL);
    factory.setUsername(USER);  
    factory.setPassword(PWD);
    IHelloWorld service = (IHelloWorld ) factory.create();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    System.out.println(http.getClass().getName());
    //org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
    http.getAuthorization().setAuthorizationType("NTLM");
    http.getAuthorization().setUserName(USER);
    http.getAuthorization().setPassword(PWD);

    http.getClient().setAllowChunking( false );
    http.getClient().setAutoRedirect( true );

    TLSClientParameters tcp = new TLSClientParameters();  
    tcp.setTrustManagers( new TrustManager[]{ new TrustAllX509TrustManager() } );  
    http.setTlsClientParameters( tcp );

    System.out.println("Invoking service...");
    String msg= "echo";
    try {
        String res = service.readMessage(msg);
        System.out.println("readMessage.result=" + res);

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Upong running this code I get following exception trace

> : domain\ is unauthorized user     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.processFaultDetail(ClientFaultConverter.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.handleMessage(ClientFaultConverter.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:845)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1624)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1513)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1318)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
>     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)    at
>   org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
>     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:81)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.readMessage(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of struggle trying to juggle between JDK 5 stack and other SOAP framework like Axis2 and CXF, I finally manged to do with a raw SOAP client that can pretty much do the job I neeed. Following is code that helped get it done even with custom NT logins than underlying ones.

```
public final class JCIFSEngine implements NTLMEngine {

    private static final int TYPE_1_FLAGS = NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET;

    public String generateType1Msg(final String domain, final String workstation)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        final Type1Message type1Message = new Type1Message(TYPE_1_FLAGS,
                domain, workstation);
        return Base64.encode(type1Message.toByteArray());
    }

    public String generateType3Msg(final String username,
            final String password, final String domain,
            final String workstation, final String challenge)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        Type2Message type2Message;
        try {
            type2Message = new Type2Message(Base64.decode(challenge));
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            throw new NTLMEngineException("Invalid NTLM type 2 message",
                    exception);
        }
        final int type2Flags = type2Message.getFlags();
        final int type3Flags = type2Flags
                & (0xffffffff ^ (NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER));
        final Type3Message type3Message = new Type3Message(type2Message,
                password, domain, username, workstation, type3Flags);
        return Base64.encode(type3Message.toByteArray());
    }

}


public class JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory implements AuthSchemeProvider {

    public AuthScheme create(final HttpContext context) {
        return new NTLMScheme(new JCIFSEngine());
    }
}
```

The use HttpClient object to register custom NTLM Engine and Auth scheme registry -

```
protected Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> getAuthRegistry() {
        Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                .<AuthSchemeProvider> create()
                .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory())
                .build();
        return authSchemeRegistry;
    }

protected CredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider(String user,
            String pass, String domain) {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,
                AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, AuthSchemes.NTLM),
                new NTCredentials(user, pass, null, domain));
        return credsProvider;
    }

        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
        httpClientBuilder.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(getAuthRegistry());
        httpClientBuilder
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(getCredentialsProvider(
                        config.getUserName(), config.getPassword(),
                        config.getDomain()));

        if (config.isProxy()) {
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(config.getProxyHost(),
                    config.getPort());
            httpClientBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
        }

        httpClientBuilder.build();
```

Hope this helps someone with similar issue. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

CXF 2.7.x does not support JDK 5. From the [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html):

> Can CXF run with JDK 1.5?
>
> Yes for CXF 2.6.x and older. Keep in mind though that Java 2 SE 5.0
>   with JDK 1.5 has reached end of life (EOL). CXF 2.7.x no longer
>   supports Java 5. In order to upgrade to 2.7.x, you must be using Java
>   6 (or newer).

Comment: Unfotunately we are stuck with JDK 1.5 stack for rest of the application so we decided to write our custom implementation using HttpClient4.x

Comment: @ManishDevraj Just curious: Not that there is anything wrong with rolling your own solution, but was CXF 2.6.x not an option?

Comment: I think from what I diagnosed the jCIFS was not used at all for some reason, hopping between CXF or Axis2 versions was not a problem...